# How to add MBR to existing UEFI USB boot device

Tags: boot, usb, uefi, mbr

I have some old legacy laptops that allow UEFI booting from the hard drive, but not from a USB flash drive. My everything flashdrive is UEFI only. Can I add MBR booting on my flash drive without wiping and starting over? My flash drive is Windows PE. I can't seem to find the answer to this.  I'd like to boot UEFI when the computer supports it, and MBR when it doesn't.

I suspect I'll get a question like what model number. It HP Probook 6560b Laptop.

Comment: You can do this when using a hybrid MBR/GPT, also known as manipulation of the protective MBR. But it's a bit risky. You need to create a real MBR with a maximum of 3 primary partitions, which have to have the same boundaries of up to the first 3 GPT partitions. The 4. and last primary partitions is the protected partition. You copy that real MBR over the protected MBR of your GPT. PS this is only a short summary, read a real tutorial.

Comment: Also in [answer](https://superuser.com/a/833384/) to duplicate question see linked page: [Hybrid MBRs: The Good, the Bad, and the So Ugly You'll Tear Your Eyes Out](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/hybrid.html)

Answer (score 0):

The
[GUID Partition Table (GPT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table)
contains what's called "Protective MBR" :

> For limited backward compatibility, the space of the legacy Master Boot Record (MBR) is still reserved in the GPT specification, but it is now used in a way that prevents MBR-based disk utilities from misrecognizing and possibly overwriting GPT disks. This is referred to as a protective MBR.

In effect, a utility that looks for an MBR on a GPT disk should
work well.

The only consideration is whether the boot software (BIOS/UEFI)
that is looking for MBR will accept such a disk.
The firmware is not as sophisticated in identifying disks as is is Windows.

You should test the flash drive to have a conclusive answer.
There is supposed to be a good chance by theory that this will work.

Comment: While it is possible to overwrite the MBR in such a way that'll let utilities correctly identify partitions (as some have commented on the question), the Protective MBR itself will absolutely not allow that to happen, as it only records one partition of type 0xEE covering the entire disk